# Brain extraction and save images as .img file

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, fmri

I have been working on Auditory data (from FIL) to read the .img files as numeric numbers of intensity of each voxels over time in array/matrix format using **AnalyzeFMRI** package in **R**. It gives me 64X64X64 number of rows of data in 96 time points. However, the images includes the eyes and other stuff than brain only. I was wondering if there is a way to extract the brain only and save it as .img file for later use. I just come to know that one software called FSL do this (I have to learned it yet), but I was looking some package in **R**.

Comment: So you're asking how to pre-process a file from what program? I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Could you be more specific about what you've tried and what constraints you're facing?